# Override NSWindow of NSPopover

Tags: swift, nswindow, nspopover

Is it possible to override the NSWindow of an NSPopover?

You can get the window with

```swift
let window = mypopover.contentViewController.view.window
```

but it seems nowhere present when subclassing NSPopover.

Where is it?

Background:
Need to lift Screen constraints from the NSWindow Object using:
`override func constrainFrameRect ...`

Comment: I don't think is't possible to change the class of the window of a `NSPopover`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Need to lift Screen constraints from the NSWindow Object using: override func constrainFrameRect ...